# Nodemailer with my company's email

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I use nodemailer to send email to my users, previously I used gmail and it work just fine, but now, Im my custom email which provided by gmail

```
admin@example.io
```

Heres the code

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  host : 'smtp.gmail.com',
  secureConnection : true,
  auth : {
    user: 'admin@example.io',
    pass: 'pass'
  }
}));
```

Since my custom account is from gmail, I expect the host to be stmp.gmail.com, but it shows this error

> { [Error: Invalid login:]}

Im not sure what is the problem over here.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleApps use the same smtp server.

Make sure your google apps administrator doesn't block SMTP relay service. 
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en

Comment: Test the smtp settings by using simple mail client like thunderbird, etc or smtp tester.